# Adjust Width of Dynamically added Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

![enter image description here][1]![My Image][2]

HTML

```
<div id ="data">
  <div>DIV1</div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    $("#Data").append('<div id="mySecondDiv"></div>');
  });
});
```

As you can See on the Image... I have one button that is adding the Divs to my Div `id ="data"`. I just want that by default I have only one div , whose width is `100%` at start, and now when I click the button it will add another and now the width of both divs will be adjusted automatically to 50%, and the functionality is goes so on

How can I achieve the adjustment of the width of the Divs?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CSS you can use this properties:

```
#data {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}
#data > div {
    display:table-cell;
    width:1%;
}
```

Check this [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6m2dqfv9/)

Comment: np mate @ColdCoffee glad to help u

Comment: but the divs are going outside after some number of divs added.can you please look back to the  Demo try to add divs more than 10

Comment: hlo danko are you around ?

Comment: @ColdCoffee I'm here yep it breaks based on the width of the window is the size. In this case depends on the content you will put in there if is some word like my example you will need to break the word like this http://jsfiddle.net/6m2dqfv9/1/

Comment: @ColdCoffee if there are multiple words it will break in lines too .. other way can be adding some overflow porperty ... but hides or scroll the content. if there will be img I guess there is no problem the img will stretch . Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6m2dqfv9/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63168/discussion-between-cold-coffee-and-danko).

Comment: One thing more please, can i delete these dynamicalyy added divs also

Comment: oh thanks aloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooot man,,, so perfffffeeeecccccttttttt ......

Comment: Hi @danko, arre you around , i need one favour

Answer (score 0):

Try with this jquery:

```
$(function(){
var i = 1;
    $("#button").click(function(){
        percent = ((1/i)*100) + '%';
        $("#Data").append('<div class="hello" style="width:'+ percent +'"></div>');
        $('.hello').css('width',percent);
        i++;
    });
});
```